Can't connect to Android 9 TV over ADB (wired or wireless)
I connected my Android 9 TV to my laptop running Windows 11 via a USB cable (new, just out of the package) since I want access to the Logcat of the TV.
ADB over network (running adb connect IP:5555) was not working before, it is not working now either: cannot connect to <IP>:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
When running adb tcpip 5555 I get the output error: no devices/emulators found.
I am able to connect to TVs running other Android versions; I tested with Android 7 and 10, both worked flawlessly without needing a USB cable even.
USB Debugging is enabled. I have tried restarting the adb server (adb server-kill, adb server-start), using Android Studio's built-in connection troubleshooter, re-installing SDK Tools; nothing seems to work. I tried restarting both my laptop and the TV several times, toggling USB debugging. No success unfortunately.
The platform-tools folder is located in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools, it is on Path in System Variables. The folder contains adb.exe.
Frankly, I am out of ideas and am desperately looking for any advice.

Please identify the make/model of Android 9 TV you are using along with does it include Google Play store.

Check Windows device manager for USB devices without installed driver (yellow exclamation mark). ADB device driver is often not installed automatically so you have to do it manually by selecting the correct driver.

Sorry, I only see these now. The model is rk3399-mid @MorrisonChang.

@Robert I have tried to follow the steps [https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb](on installing the Google USB Driver) and [https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#InstallingDriver](on installing OEM USB drivers but the device does not even show up in the Device Manager. The Google USB Driver option is installed from SDK Tools in Android Studio and I can see the files in the destination folder. But perhaps it's not configured properly then?
